# When I read a file and append it's contents into a list, why does it add a '/n' to it's values?

Tags: python

So this is the layout of my file that is being read:

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

And this is the my code:

```
def readfile(path):
    file = open(path, 'r')
    scorelist = []
    for line in file:
        line.strip
        scorelist.append(line)
    return scorelist

l =readfile('highscores.txt')
print(l)
```

I just want to save those values to a list, but when I print the list my output is:

```
['0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0']
```

How do you fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few issues:

1. You are appending strings to your array, **not** numbers. To fix this, just call `float()` to convert the values you're reading into floats.
2. You never actually call `.strip()`, all you do is `line.strip`, which does nothing. This is why the newline characters aren't being removed. Just fix this typo.

This code should work:

```
def readfile(path):
    scorelist = []
    for line in open(path, 'r'):
        scorelist.append(float(line.strip()))
    return scorelist


l = readfile('highscores.txt')
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole code can be simplified to just:

```
def readfile(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        scorelist = [line.strip() for line in f]
        #scorelist = [int(line.strip()) for line in f]  # for int values
    return scorelist
```

(It is generally considered to use the `with...` context manager so you don't forget to close open files ;) )